# When should I be using React.cloneElement vs this.props.children?

Tags: reactjs

I am still a noob at React and in many examples on the internet, I see this variation in rendering child elements which I find confusing. Normally I see this:

```
class Users extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Users</h2>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But then I see an example like this:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
     component="div"
     transitionName="example"
     transitionEnterTimeout={500}
     transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
     >
     {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
       key: this.props.location.pathname
      })}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

Now I understand the api but the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) don't exactly make clear when I should be using it.

So what does one do which the other can't? Could someone explain this to me with better examples?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEGg-3pIHlE this guy is showing how he uses cloneElement. Check this out for some examples

Answer (score 305, accepted):

`props.children` isn't the actual children; It is the *descriptor* of the children. So you don't have actually anything to change; you can't change any props, or edit any functionality; you can only *read from it*. If you need to make any modifications you have to create *new elements* using `React.CloneElement`.

https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-react-cloneelement-to-extend-functionality-of-children-components

An example:

main render function of a component such as `App.js`:

```
render() {   
    return(
            <Paragraph>
              <Sentence>First</Sentence>
              <Sentence>Second</Sentence>
              <Sentence>Third</Sentence>
            </Paragraph>   
    ) 
}
```

now let's say you need to add an `onClick` to each child of `Paragraph`; so in your `Paragraph.js` you can do:

```
render() {
        return (
          <div>
          {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
              onClick: this.props.onClick })   
         })}
         </div>
       ) 
}
```

then simply you can do this:

```
render() {   
  return(
        <Paragraph onClick={this.onClick}>
          <Sentence>First</Sentence>
          <Sentence>Second</Sentence>
          <Sentence>Third</Sentence>
        </Paragraph>   
   ) 
}
```

**Note:** the `React.Children.map` function will only see the *top level* elements, it does not see any of the things that those elements render; meaning that you are providing the direct props to children (here the `<Sentence />` elements). If you need the props to be passed down further, let's say you will have a `<div></div>` inside one of the `<Sentence />` elements that wants to use the `onClick` prop then in that case you can use the Context API to do it. Make the `Paragraph` the provider and the `Sentence` elements as consumer.

Comment: This is a clear answer with a real world example. It needs more upvotes.

Comment: Agree with @SeaWarrior404 - I would guess the OP was looking looking to iterate over a collection rather than a single child because his user interface has "Users"/plural as the title. Using `React.Children.map` in conjunction with `React.cloneElement` as @vennesa points out, is very powerful

Answer (score 75):

**Edit:**

Look at [Vennesa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50441271/1689055) instead, which is a better explanation.

**Original:**

First of all, the `React.cloneElement` example only works if your child is a single React element.

For almost everything `{this.props.children}` is the one you want.
Cloning is useful in some more advanced scenarios, where a parent sends in an element and the child component needs to change some props on that element or add things like ref for accessing the actual DOM element.

In the example above, the parent which gives the child does not know about the key requirement for the component, therefore it creates a copy of the element it is given and adds a key based on some unique identifier in the object. For more info on what key does: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

Answer (score 30):

In fact, `React.cloneElement` is not strictly associated with `this.props.children`.

It's useful whenever you need to clone react elements(`PropTypes.element`) to add/override props, without wanting the parent to have knowledge about those component internals(e.g, attaching event handlers or assigning `key`/`ref` attributes).

Also react elements are **immutable**.

> React.cloneElement( element, [props], [...children] ) is almost equivalent to:
>   `<element.type {...element.props} {...props}>{children}</element.type>`

---

However, the `children` prop in React is especially used for containment (aka [composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)), pairing with `React.Children` API and `React.cloneElement`, component that uses props.children can handle more logic(e.g., state transitions, events, DOM measurements etc) internally while yielding the rendering part to wherever it's used, React Router [`<switch/>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L38) or compound component [`<select/>`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEGg-3pIHlE) are some great examples.

One last thing that worth mentioning is that react elements are not restricted to props.children.

```
function SplitPane(props) {
  return (
    <div className="SplitPane">
      <div className="SplitPane-left">
        {props.left}
      </div>
      <div className="SplitPane-right">
        {props.right}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <SplitPane
      left={
        <Contacts />
      }
      right={
        <Chat />
      } />
  );
}
```

They can be whatever props that makes sense, the key was to define a good contract for the component, so that the consumers of it can be decoupled from the underlying implementation details, regardless whether it's using `React.Children`, `React.cloneElement`, or even `React.createContext`.