# Using React.cloneElement() in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to know how to use cloneElement syntax in JSX. I read Docs and tried examples but still don't have any clue.

```
class ABC extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
}
render() {
  return(
  <div>
    {React.cloneElement()}
  </div>
  )
}
}
```

Comment: read here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement , they have provide examples also

Comment: Possible duplicate [When should I be using React.cloneElement vs this.props.children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521798/when-should-i-be-using-react-cloneelement-vs-this-props-children)

Comment: @stack26 I have already read Docs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the **[documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)**:

> Clone and return a new React element using element as the starting
>   point. The resulting element will have the original element’s props
>   with the new props merged in shallowly. New children will replace
>   existing children. key and ref from the original element will be
>   preserved.

A valid use case for cloneElement is when you wish to add one/more props to the elements passed a children by the parent.You would simply  map over all the children and clone them by adding new props for instance.

```
return (
  <div style={styles}>
    {React.Children.map(children, child => {
      console.log(child);
      return React.cloneElement(child, {newProp}, null);
    })}
  </div>
)
```

Check a **[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xvwpql1q7p)**

Comment: Should you please explain where  you get `child`  in `React.Children.map`?

Comment: In the above example `children` comes from `props.children`.

`child` is a param passed to an arrow function.
In ES5:
```jsx
{React.Children.map(children, function(child){
      console.log(child);
      return React.cloneElement(child, {newProp}, null);
})}
```



https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap