# why i need to write cloneElement then the child component will rerender

Tags: reactjs

if i only write {this.props.children}, the third row can not change every second.i need to write {React.cloneElement(this.props.children)}, why?

It is parent下午1:50:27.
It is child下午1:50:27.
It is child下午1:28:30.

https://codepen.io/yemos/pen/jQveVx/?editors=0011

```js
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { date: new Date() };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.setState({date: new Date()}), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h5>It is parent{this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h5>
  {React.cloneElement(this.props.children)}
  {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('componentWillMount');
  }
  render() {
    console.log('render');
    return <h5>It is child{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h5>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<A><B/></A>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37522586/2630817 this may be helpful

Comment: Because React will only render the updated DOM. You're making an Interval for updating state of ` A` and passing ` B` as props to  ` A` so every seconds ` A` has a new state then render method will only render the updated DOM. ` B` as a prop is not changing you are passing it as a static object it is not changing over time so ' A' is not getting any change.But when you clone the child you are making a new copy of it so every seconds a new copy of it is rendered because anytime ` A` state changes React will trigger render method.

Answer (score 1):

[cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) clone and return a new React element.

But [react elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element) are immutable. Once you create an element, you can’t change its children or attributes.

Since, you're just returning new date in component B, it will not be updated. You will need to use state date and do the same as you did in the component A.

While cloning works, it's just because, it returns a new react element. But `props.children` will return the same element and only updates when it requires.

`{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}` just returns static date.

Comment: write <B/> direct,it also the same element,and its props or state not change,but it will re-render.
it confused me,because i think they have no diff.
      `<div>
        <h5>It is parent{this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h5>
        {this.props.children}
        <B/>
      </div>`

Comment: ah, i think you din't get my answer. using state date will be fine, but using new date won't  work due to immutability. thus, i suggest you to re-read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `B` is rendered as a child of `A`, a re-render of component A will not trigger `render` method of `component B` and hence no new updates will be flushed to `component B` which in your case is the `Date data`. Using React.cloneElement ensures that a new element is created for the children and hence the updated value is re-evaluated.

Comment: thanks, so how can i force re-render B component without use clone method. i want to force update it , but B has only one complex data structure as prop like <B peer={complexobject}>,no state,B render itself by the complexobject.

Comment: You can trigger a render of B without cloneelement by having a wrapper which renders `<A><B/></A>` and has the setInterval logic in its componentDidMount method, However doing this is an overkill and its better to use cloneElement for your case