# Iterating over child components and rendering each wrapped in a higher order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently experiencing an issue when it comes to wrapping the child elements of a parent element in a higher order component and then rendering them.

Consider the following structure:

```
return (
<div className="App">
  <FocusProvider>
    <TestComponent testProp={'Foo'}/>
    <TestComponent testProp={'Foo'}/>
    <TestComponent testProp={'Foo'}/>
  </FocusProvider>
</div>
);
```

Where `FocusProvider` is the parent element and `TestComponent` is the child element that needs to be wrapped in a higher order component that provides lifecycle methods to it as well as inject props.

And then the higher order component called `hoc` which overrides the prop for `TestComponent` and provides a lifecycle method to it as well looks like:

```
const hoc = (WrappedComponent, prop) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
   shouldComponentUpdate = (prevProps, prop) => {
     return !prevProps === prop
   }
   render(){
     return <WrappedComponent testProp={prop}/>
   }
 }
}
```

The render method of `FocusProvider` looks like :

```
 render(){
  return(
   this.props.children.map(child => {
    let Elem = hoc(child, 'bar')
    return <Elem/>
  })
 ) 
}
```

When I try and render that I get `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

When I try and change it to :

```
render(){
  return(
    this.props.children.map(child => {
       let elem = hoc(child, 'bar')
       return elem
    })
  ) 
 }
```

Nothing is returned from render. I am confused because I can render the chil components directly, but not the child components wrapped in the HOC:

```
 render(){
  return(
    this.props.children.map(child => {
       return child  //This works
    })
  ) 
 }
```

I want to avoid using `React.cloneElement` as I don't want to trigger re-renders by cloning the child elements every time the parent updates.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: FYI https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method

Answer (score 1):

`hoc` is a function which returns a `Component` not `jsx`. You cannot wrap the `children` in a `HOC` like that.

But you can wrap just `FocusProvider` and pass the prop down to it's children using `cloneElement`. There is no problem in use `cloneElement` like this. Is a [common pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521798/when-should-i-be-using-react-cloneelement-vs-this-props-children/50441271#50441271) actually.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FocusProvider bar="baz">
        <Child />
        <Child />
        <Child />
      </FocusProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

const withHOC = Component => props => {
  return <Component foo="bar" {...props} />;
};

const FocusProvider = withHOC(({ children, foo, bar }) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, { foo, bar });
  });
});

const Child = ({ foo, bar }) => (
  <>
    {foo}
    {bar}
  </>
);
```

[image: Edit great-kowalevski-96wum]